# I can't convert my ajax $.get to $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I try to convert an ajax function that I do not understand. Here the original function :

```
$.get(page, function (data) {
  $('.former-students__list').append(data.student
  $('#load-more').data('next-page', data.next_page);
})
```

I'd like to convert it to make it more readable (with $ .ajax), So I could clearly see the events success, and so on.

Here is what I tried but it doesn't work

```
$.ajax({
 url: page,
 data: function (data) {
  $('.former-students__list').append(data.students);
  $('#load-more').data('next-page', data.next_page);
 }
 'success': 'Cool, it's work')
},
```

Thank you for your help and your explanations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because the `data` parameter should be an object, a string or an array which you use to *send* data to the server. However, given your `$.get` sample, you don't actually need to use it in `$.ajax` at all.

Instead, the `success` property should be a function which receives the data back from the request and then acts on it. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: page,
  success: function(data) {
    $('.former-students__list').append(data.students);
    $('#load-more').data('next-page', data.next_page);
  })
});
```

For more information, please read the [jQuery $.ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
 url: page,
 success: function (data) {
  $('.former-students__list').append(data.students);
  $('#load-more').data('next-page', data.next_page);
 }
})
```

I think the `data` property is for POST request payloads.

Answer (score 1):

you should fire the success callback event so try this :

```
  $.ajax({
      url: page,  
      success: function(data) {
         $('.former-students__list').append(data.students);
         $('#load`enter code here`-more').data('next-page', data.next_page);
      }
   });
```